# String Array in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, arrays

I need to work with a persistent String Array (n Rows, 1 column).
* On first running the app, the String Array needs to be created empty.
* On subsequent app executions the Array will be populated from a File and the contents need to be available throughout the rest of the app.
* As the app is executed, the Array needs to be able to 'grow' in row count
* As the app is executed, the Array rows need to be able to grow in length
* The user will have the option to Clear the Array of previous entries.
* At the end, the String Array contents will be written back to a File.

I find a lot of references to Putting and Getting from an existing SharedPreferences String[] but, in the newness of my Android development, I am struggling with how to proceed.

EDIT Follows...
The data itself suggests using an Array

Example:

```
MAIN ST.    F55     63      KY08:57 12142015--------KY11:24 12142015345TMH  KY13:57 12142015
MAIN ST.    F56     WYE123  IN08:57 12142015--------KY11:24 12142015--------KY13:57 12142015
1ST ST.     F57     --------KY08:57 12142015--------KY11:24 12142015789FPF  KY13:57 12142015
1ST ST.     F58     456FPF  KY08:57 12142015998FPF  KY11:24 12142015--------KY13:57 12142015
1ST ST.     F59     789TTM  KY08:57 12142015--------KY11:24 121420151234DG  KY13:57 12142015
```

I first need to have this data in a File
Then in one GUI I check for the existence of the file.
If one exists, fine
If none exists, I create one.

Then, in subsequent GUI's, I must check for the existence of parameters
If they do not already exist, add them to the existing data lines.
If they already exist, notify the user

And so on and on.

Then when all of the current 'pass' data has been collected via multiple, separate GUI's, I have to write out the whole data-set into the file.

My reason for thinking that I need a SharedPreference approach is the need to find and check data from GUI to GUI as the user progresses through the app. 
If that 'belief' is wrong, I am open to better approach suggestions.

EDIT 2 follows....
On further study of web references, I am beginning to think that perhaps the best approach for this data and how the data needs to change might be to use a SQLite approach.   Any ideas about this?

Any assistance/suggestions you might have would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences for save a data. for save all of matrix you can use for loop. do you have problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, based on the data, how it needs to be manipulated and the pros and cons of using a SharedPreferences approach, I have decided to go with a SQLite approach.

With that approach I should be able to readily check:
* if the necessary table exists (if not create it)
* if the necessary Field1 + Field2 exists  (if not create a new record)
* and I will be able to modify the record's Field3 contents as needed

Then when the user's actions are complete I can convert the SQLite table 'records' into strings and write them out as a File and then either DROP or PURGE the associated SQLite table (until needed next time).

I sincerely appreciate all of your suggestions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i would discourage you from using sharedpreferences for anything else than preferences. means things that change rarely - really rarely and are really lightweight. do not put much data in there. less is better. the data structures underlying sharedpreferences are not a database.

another note. it is not a string list, but it would be a string set. sets are not necessarily ordered, nor do they necessarily keep their order. means - it is not rows. its a collection of strings that can come back in any fun order (usually there is some, but that depends on the implementation which i do not know)

now you could go and make your own list, your own data structure, save it into a string and read it out, use json to do exactly that or something similar, or better - use a database, which would exactly do that.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

explains it, but as you'll see its something that might take some time.

now dont get me wrong, but i have to warn you about the following approach. it is valid, but has many problems and is far from thread safe. it will not be a problem as long as you only open it from the ui thread and do not keep anything in memory to cache - if you do it will create lots of problems.
your problem of adding a line and clearing can be solved by using a file. just a simple file

look here
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage

the change is to append when writing:
    openFileOutput("filename", Context.MODE_APPEND);

see the context mode? now you can basically just write one line and append every time.

if you wanna clear the file, just deleteFile("filename")

this is as said not threadsafe, but can be a viable option if used carefully.

Comment: As the user moves through the app, the data changes on each GUI.  But at the end of the multiple, sequential GUI's, the data no longer changes.  I am guessing that using a File IO approach for each GUI need would be a considerably slower process.  Am I wrong?

Comment: actually it would be a lot faster than sharedpreferences. sharedpref is really not too much else. especially for the usecase as you described it, the file-io aproach would even be faster than sqlite in this case. yet its not exactly safe, so sqlite is definitely the better (more flexible and safe) choice. who knows how your usecase changes and it sucks to change data structures later ;)

Comment: the main problem with the file-io approach is really concurrency. as you only need append, this span is so tiny, that it usually shouldnt be a problem at all and should be neglible. so before you believe everybody saying generally better to use sql - its true - but also more work, where fileio is simpler. really a matter of choice. i have built myself a tiny abstraction to use sqlite as document-store. that helps not to have to write all that crap all the time and makes it easy enough. from scratch not so much though :)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this step to achieve what you want with sharedPreference

1. create the class Parent for SharePreference
2. Create your empty Array
3. Convert Your empty array to String and put it on SharedPreference

to call your empty array from sharedPreference

1. Call your sharedPreference using your key
2. Convert the String to array
3. You get your array from the sharePreference

Hope it helps, and maybe this link will help you : 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

Answer (score 0):

You can use my open-source library called [prefser](https://github.com/pwittchen/prefser), which solves this problem and uses `SharedPreferences` and Gson under the hood. It's basically wrapper for default Android mechanism.

You can use it in the following way:

```
Prefser prefser = new Prefser(context); // create Prefser object
prefser.put("key", Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three")); // save array of Strings
String[] value = prefser.get("key", String[].class, new String[]{}); // read array of Strings
```

For more information check repository of the project, tests and `README.md` file.

Link: https://github.com/pwittchen/prefser

Please note, `SharedPreferences` have some limitations and shouldn't be used for storing large amount of data. If you expect a lot of data, consider using SQLite database or another type of database (e.g. with NoSQL or similar approach if you strive for simplicity).

Comment: The Array begins with nothing in it and then grows with user input until the data is saved off into a File.  One typical File (populated with Array data from app) is 75KB.   What would be a 'large amount of data'?